# PDF PHP library that converts html tag containing images to PDF

Tags: php, html, pdf

I just want to ask if there are any free/opensource or are there even any existing PHP class library that can convert HTML to PHP using the tags as its image source?

Because I have created a web app that contains Google Maps in it and now I want to save the generated map, instead of saving it using `printscrn` I would like to convert it to PDF. Is it even possible?

Can you give me guys a link to the library if ever there are existing ones?

I have already looked for `fpdf` and `tcpdf` but on their examples all images is contained on the file directory.

Thanks

Comment: is dompdf that easy to use? is there any available documentations and examples? thanks

Comment: Thanks Ali Nfr for the edit.

Comment: dompdf https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf very easy to use

Answer (score 0):

There is the library [HTML2PDF](http://html2pdf.fr/en/default) (on [github](https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf/)) licensed under LGPL. It is based on TCPDF and very easy to use.

Comment: I don't know how to use github but I'll look into it.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have tried and successfully converted html to pdf using wkhtmltopdf[1] binary sometime back (including images).

Download wkhtmltopdf binary which is compatible to your base server o/s and use a php wrapper class similar to this[2] (i haven't tested this wrapper class[2] but it should serve your purpose)

There are plenty of php wrappers available for wkhtmltopdf binary, so you can find one easily if this[2] didn't work well for your purpose.

[1] http://wkhtmltopdf.org/

[2] http://mikehaertl.github.io/phpwkhtmltopdf/

Comment: it can get images without having those images exisiting in the directory? thanks

Comment: u mean using web url resources ? It should work. since it's same as keeping images locally and put the local path within image tags. make sure you have active internet connection when you testing it.

Comment: I'm sorry im not that good in english and not that kind of familiar with terms either.. Im using google maps. the map is enclosed in a div. Can I capture the map using this api?

Comment: Simply put.. if you can view it on web browser as html, you can convert it to pdf using wkhtmltopdf given that you use correct configurations using wrapper class (read wrapper class documentation) according to your input html (there are several input parameters to fine tune the outcome in wkhtmltopdf).


You'll never learn it just by asking questions here in stackoverflow. you have to jump into it and do some trial and error until outcome satisfies you.




If you fall into trouble or dead end you can always count on stackoverflow again.

Comment: Can I use it on CPANEL? I'm just new to this kind of technology